# How to highlight or add annotation for a line in eclipse?(java)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

I am now writing a small Eclipse Plugin. 
 
In the plugin, the program will get the .java and line number in this .java
 
My question is How to use the file name and line number to highlight the entire line and jump to it?

For example, the program get template.java and line 38, how can I highlight the line 38 in template.java and jump to it?

I am new to eclipse plugin. 
 
Please help 
 
Thanks a lots

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Have you tried anything in particular yet?  It's probably going to be easier to get help if you include the code you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code adapted from the standard `Goto Line` action:

```java
private void gotoLine(int line) {

  ITextEditor editor = getTextEditor();
  // TODO check for null editor

  IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();
  IDocument document = provider.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());

  try {
     int start = document.getLineOffset(line);

     int length = document.getLineLength(line);

     editor.selectAndReveal(start, length);

     // Ensure editor is active - you may not need this
     IWorkbenchPage page = editor.getSite().getPage();
     page.activate(editor);
   } catch (BadLocationException x) {
  // ignore
   }
}
```

This needs a `getTextEditor()` method, which could be something like

```java
ITextEditor getTextEditor()
{
  IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

  IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();

  if (editor instanceof ITextEditor) {
     return (ITextEditor)editor;
  }

  return null;
}
```

depending on how your plugin runs there might be better ways of determining the text editor.

Comment: Thanks for replying.   Platform.getworkbench() has an error that "The method getWorkbench() is undefined for the type Platform". I should import something? or add any dependencies?

Comment: Sorry my fault, it should be PlatformUI

Comment: Thanks! May I ask for a further question? How to switch to the target TextEditor? I mean we have more than one .java in the project. Can I specific which editor to highlight the line?

Comment: `IWorkbenchPage` has a `getEditorReferences` which will let you search through the open editors. The `IDE.openEditor` methods will open a new editor.

Comment: sorry, for IDE.openEditor(),  IDE mean what? I cannot use IDE in my Eclipse SDK

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE` provides some static helper methods to make `IWorkbenchPage.openEditor` easier to use.

Comment: Thanks a lots!!but one question to go.  
some import line will zip as one line and the above method just count the line number by counting those import line as one line.
can the linenumber point to the real line number?